# Memory analyse with WebSphere Liberty on linux

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection, websphere-liberty

I look at my Liberty instances in Linux RHEL environment. I'm trying to understand how they are doing in terms of memory usage. The recommendation is to give 2GB to the instance. One of the instances, I've given 2.5GB:

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx2560m
```

Verbose GC is reporting that it does GC every 300s - 600s, which seems very good to me. Server is in constant use, but the use is not too extensive yet.

Now, top reports to me from server:

```
Mem:  16334412k total, 15686252k used,   648160k free
```

But for the process itself, it says:

```
4336m (VIRT), 1.3g (RES)
```

I don't see neither of those reflecting 2.5GB. This is some type of cloud server. /proc/cpuinfo reports two GenuineIntel cpu:s (family: 6, model 45, cpu cores: 1).

Probably following GC cycle frequency is my best option to spot memory problems, before they become real problems. And top can give me an indication if I have available RAM to give these instances without fear of swap kicking in.

Now my question is, what does top actually tell me ? Back in 90's it was known that top implementation did not handle multiple cpu's too well. Is that still the case ?